# While touch swipe over the owl carousel, it isn't swiping down

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is my header section, where in the mobile responsive or media screen, I can't touch swipe down over the area.

I have tried to reduce the height of the section but no changes. Since the template is good, I am expecting some minute changes can be helpful

```
 <section class="home-slider js-fullheight owl-carousel bg-white">
      <div class="slider-item js-fullheight">
        <div class="overlay"></div>
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row d-md-flex no-gutters slider-text js-fullheight align-items-center justify-content-end" data-scrollax-parent="true" data-bs-touch="true">
            <div class="one-third order-md-last">
                <img class="js-fullheight " src="/static/images/7.jpg" alt="background" style="border-radius: 25px;">
                <h3 class="vr">Builders & Developers</h3>
            </div>
              <div class="one-forth d-flex js-fullheight align-items-center ftco-animate" data-scrollax=" properties: { translateY: '70%' }">
                <div class="text">
                    <h1 class="mb-4" style="font-family: 'Lobster Two', sans-serif; border-radius: 25px;">We don't just build, we build legacies</h1>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="slider-item js-fullheight">
        <div class="overlay"></div>
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row d-flex no-gutters slider-text js-fullheight align-items-center justify-content-end" data-scrollax-parent="true" data-bs-touch="true">
            <div class="one-third order-md-last">
              <img class="js-fullheight" src="/static/images/cover1.jpg" style="border-radius: 25px;">
                <h3 class="vr">Since - 2014</h3>
            </div>
              <div class="one-forth d-flex js-fullheight align-items-center ftco-animate" data-scrollax=" properties: { translateY: '70%' }">
                <div class="text">
                    <h1 class="mb-4" style="font-family: 'Lobster Two', sans-serif; border-radius: 25px;">Innovate, Build and Transform</h1>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
```